# Restrict JQuery append() to size of parent div elment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created an empty *< div >* element with a certain size and borders (the actual size is not relevant).

Now i want to create a JS function that inserts several radio buttons within this box (in this example *#b_id*).

However, my code doesnt seem to care about the size of its parent-element. Its returning the elements across the whole page.

**Question:** How can i fix the insertion of the radio buttons to the size of *#b_id* with a scrollbar?

---

Note: This is an example code.

```js
function box_creator() {
   $('#b_id').append(`<input type="radio">2</input><br>
   <input type="radio">3</input><br>
   <input type="radio">4</input><br>
   <input type="radio">5</input><br>`);
 };
```

```css
.a {
   border: 4px solid rgb(60, 131, 121);
   height: 200px;
   width = 800px;

 }
#b_id, #c_id {
   border: 4px solid rgb(60, 131, 121);
   height: 100px;
   width = 400px;
   margin: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">   A   
  <div class="b" id="b_id">
       <div >LOG</div>
   </div>
   <div  class="c" id="c_id">
      <div>TYPE</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do JS will care about parent element's height while appending elements? can you please elaborate your problem? What is happening right now ? and what should be happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `css` use `max-width` instead of `width`. And add `overflow: auto;`. Update this in `.a` as well as `#b_id, #c_id`.

check below code. Click `Create Box` button to add `radio buttons` and check output.

```js
function box_creator() {
  $('#b_id').append(`<input type="radio">2</input><br>
   <input type="radio">3</input><br>
   <input type="radio">4</input><br>
   <input type="radio">5</input><br>`);
};
```

```css
.a {
  border: 4px solid rgb(60, 131, 121);
  height: 200px;
  max-width=800px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#b_id,
#c_id {
  border: 4px solid rgb(60, 131, 121);
  height: 100px;
  max-width=400px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" onclick="box_creator()" value = "Create Box" />

<div class="a"> A
  <div class="b" id="b_id">
    <div>LOG</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c" id="c_id">
    <div>TYPE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```